# Kummer Theory - Example of Subgroup of $K^{*}$ containing $K^{*m}$ for global fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, kummer-theory

I am trying to understand Kummer theory and I wish to apply it to global fields, so our field $K$ containing $\mu_m$ should be $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$.

Let $B$ be a subgroup of $K^{*}$ containing $K^{*m}$. We define $K_B:=K(B^{1/m})$ to be the compositum of all $K(a^{1/m})$ such that $a\in B$.
Define $G=\text{Gal}(K_B/K)$.

(This is necessarily a Galois extension as $K_B$ is a splitting field for $x^n-a$ for any $a\in B$.)

We then have the Kummer Pairing, 
$$\kappa:G\:\text{x}\:B\rightarrow B$$

given by $\kappa(\sigma,a)=\frac{\sigma(\alpha)}{\alpha}$, for $\alpha^m=a$.

My question is this:

Can we think of an explicit example of $B$ such that $(B:K^{*m})$ is finite? I am struggling to see how this works

Comment: Or, alternatively, what is the subgroup $B$ under which $K_B=K(a^{1/m})$?

Comment: Do you have a thorough understanding of the situation when $m=2$?

Comment: Wait, why should $K=\Bbb Q(\zeta_m)$ don't you also want the case $\Bbb F_p(\zeta_m)[T]$ to handle arbitrary global fields?

Comment: @AdamHughes, For an arbitrary global field yes, but, I should have been more clear in stating this, I am studying Kummer theory in order to prove Kronecker-Weber, so I am really only interested in extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Lubin After thinking about it, I guess I don't have a thorough understanding of when $m=2$. I know the base field must be $\mathbb{Q}$, but if I want to find a subgroup $B$ of $\mathbb{Q}^{\text{x}}$ such that ${\mathbb{Q}^{x}}^2\subset B$ I am stumped.  Further, I want to know what this subgroup will be to ensure that $K_B=K(\sqrt{a})$, and I think the fact that it is an infinite group is confusing me slightly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let’s look at the case $m=2$ for simplicity. As you’ve seen, in this case your base field is $\Bbb Q$. Let’s not look at $\Bbb Q^\times$ but at $\Bbb Q^{>0}$. This simplifies some things slightly, and effectively allows us to consider fields gotten by taking square roots of positive integers only, i.e. real quadratic extensions of $\Bbb Q$ and their compositums.

Now, as a group, $\Bbb Q^{>0}$ is the direct sum of infinitely many infinite cyclic groups, one for each prime. This is the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. You can write  $\Bbb Q^{>0}=\bigoplus_pp^{\Bbb Z}$, if you accept the sumbol “$\oplus$” for groups written multiplicatively. Now, of course, we get
$$
\bigl(\Bbb Q^{>0}\bigr)^2=\bigoplus_pp^{2\Bbb Z}\,,
$$
equal to $(\Bbb Q^\times)^2$.

And if you take the quotient of $\Bbb Q^{>0}$ over this, i.e. if you take $\Bbb Q^{>0}\big/\bigl(\Bbb Q^{>0}\bigr)^2$, you get an infinite direct sum of cyclic groups of order $2$, one for each prime. I’m sure you know that Kummer Theory says that this is the dual of the Galois group of the compositum of all quadratic extensions of $\Bbb Q$, over $\Bbb Q$. Let’s denote this infinite extension of $\Bbb Q$ as $\mathcal Q$. Then the Galois group $G=\text{Gal}(\mathcal Q/\Bbb Q)$ is direct product of infinitely many cyclic groups of order $2$. Say we want to talk about a compositum $k$ of finitely many real quadratic extensions of $\Bbb Q$, gotten by adjoining square roots of the square-free positive integers $\{n_1,\cdots,n_r\}$. Then the Galois group of $k$ over $\Bbb Q$ will be $F\cong G/H$. Taking duals, the quotient becomes a subgroup and vice-versa, so we have
$$
1\longrightarrow H\longrightarrow G\longrightarrow F\longrightarrow 1\,,
$$
giving rise to
$$
1\longleftarrow H^{\text D}\longleftarrow \Bbb Q^{>0}\big/\Bbb Q^2\longleftarrow F^{\text D}\longleftarrow 1\,.
$$
So we’re talking about a finite subgroup of $\Bbb Q^{>0}\big/\Bbb Q^2 $, in other words, as you have clearly recognized from your posting, a subgroup $S\subset\Bbb Q^{>0}$ such that $(S :\Bbb Q^2)$ is finite. But now it’s clear which subgroup you’re talking about: it’s $\bigl\langle\Bbb Q^2,n_1,\cdots,n_r\bigr\rangle$, where the angle-bracket notation is meant to denote the group generated by the things inside. I think this answers your specific question.

I know I’ve gone into painful detail on things you have already understood. It was partly to make my own ideas clear and partly to go through everything step by step and try to be very explicit about how things fit together.

Comment: I very much appreciate the detail you have gone into. In my head I assumed there would be a very easy way to show this, and I think I knew the subgroup would be something like $\langle\mathbb{Q}^2,a\rangle$ if I wanted to find $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a})$,for example, but not that I would have to find an exact sequence of dual spaces.. Is it always true that if $S$ is a finite subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}^{>0}/ \mathbb{Q}^2$ then $\mathbb{Q}^2$ will have finite index in $S$? Once again, thanks for your help.

Comment: To your last question, Yes, sure. That follows from one of the basic group Isomorphism theorems. Beyond that, I think you don’t need to look at the reversing arrows and the two exact sequences, once you get the hang of the whole thing. And by the way, if you have further questions, please don’t hesitate to e-mail me.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you take for B the multiplicative subgroup generated by K*$^m$ and an element of K* which is not in  K*$^m$ ? More "concretely", take m to be a prime p. If you think of the multiplication in K* as an addition (group law, so the notation does not matter), then K*/K*$^p$ is a vector space over the prime field **F**$_p$. Any finite dimensional sub-vector space of K*/K*$^p$ will give you what you want. Of course, the case p = 2 covers the example given by Lubin .